# Font-Awesome fonts (woff) not loading via Netlify CDN

Tags: font-awesome, webfonts, netlify

I have a Netlify CDN pulling files via my GitHub, and everything works perfectly fine it seems, except loading the fonts. I'm rather new to CDNs but have been researching and learning a lot.

But... I've spent 4 hours researching how to enable this, and the only thing I can find in their documentation or anyone else with similar problems, is that I need to create a _header file in the root directory, but they don't specify anything to do with the fonts. They just tell me this example code.

Site link:
https://www.netlify.com/docs/headers-and-basic-auth/

Example Header:

```
## A path:
/templates/index.html
  # Headers for that path:
  X-Frame-Options: DENY
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
/templates/index2.html
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Does anyone have any experience with this? I'm about to go find a new CDN, but not sure who else is reliable.

Comment: By the way I'm using this CDN to just purely host static js, css, files.

Comment: Are you having CORS issues or the mime-type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Netlify allows for you to setup Headers in your pages using a structured configuration in the `netlify.toml` file.

To add a header for the woff content type you need a header equivalent of:

```html
/*.woff
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Content-Type: application/font-woff
```

Using the [Netlify Tool](https://play.netlify.com/headers) to test valid headers, your settings in the config would be:

`netlify.toml`

```js
[[headers]]
  for = "/*.woff"
  [headers.values]
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "*"
    Content-Type = "application/font-woff"
```

The `netlify.toml` file exists at the root of the site on Netlify.
The paths need to be valid also and the above is just an example.

Comment: Talves thank you very much for getting back to me. Yes I'm having the CORs issue from what I've gathered. I've been able to set up a "CDN" via another hosting, just calling and setting up the files and allowing the access control via htaccess, but I wasn't able to find anything via netlify, I'll definitely try your solution.

Comment: I have this so far, if I want to add another font do I just separate the line with a comma or duplicate all three lines?

[
/*.woff
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: assets/vendor/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0
    Content-Type: application/font-woff ]

Comment: Actually I before I even upload I think I misread what I was supposed to put where. Lol. URL for font first, then the ACAO needs to be site allowed to use the CDN.

Comment: Right. These settings are all valid header settings, so you would follow the specs for http headers. The tools just help you set them up in the config file the correct way.

Comment: Some reason I have it set up but I'm still getting the issue.. Care to take a look if I'm doing it right? I've tried it with and without the full url path.

Answer (score 1):

The file `_headers` in the root directory can be used for configuration of headers according to the documentation https://www.netlify.com/docs/headers-and-basic-auth/.

The following examples demonstrates how all ttf and woff fonts in the directory `/assets/fonts/` and its sub directories can be given access from any origin.

```
# Custom Netlify Headers
# https://www.netlify.com/docs/headers-and-basic-auth/

/assets/fonts/*.woff
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Content-Type: application/font-woff

/assets/fonts/*.ttf
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Content-Type: application/font-ttf
```